# create very large queue for python multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I would like to create a queue of about 256K paths to files and have the paths dequeued and processed by parallel worker processes. This is multiprocessing rather than threads.

However, when I create a multiprocessing.queue there seems to be a hard limit at 32K objects in the queue. This might be even smaller if the objects were full paths to files, as intended.

What would be an alternate way to create a multiserver queue for multiprocessing?

```
import multiprocessing
import sys

q = multiprocessing.Queue()

for i in range(32768 * 2):
    print i
    try:
        q.put('abcdef')
    except:
        print "Unexpected error on ()".format(i), sys.exc_info()[0]
        raise
```

yields:

```
...
32766
32767
Traceback (most recent call last):
Unexpected error on () <type 'exceptions.KeyboardInterrupt'>
  File "/Users/Wes/Dropbox/Programming/ElectionTransparency/vops_addons/dead/tryq.py", line 13, in <module>
    q.put('abc')
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 101, in put
    if not self._sem.acquire(block, timeout):
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: The idea with such a queue is usually to put items in and take them out concurrently. You wouldn't have this problem if you started the workers first instead of waiting to completely populate the queue up front.

Comment: Maybe consider using a Redis list with `LPUSH` and `BLPOP` then you can insert and remove and process items from any machine in your network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I finally found that worked. I made the array of paths available to all the worker processes and used a multiprocessing.Value() object to create a shared index into the array protected with a lock.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock, Value
import os
import sys
import time

def info(title, lock, item=None):
    pid = os.getpid()
    lock.acquire()
    print '<', title, item,' ', __name__, pid, '>'
    sys.stdout.flush()
    lock.release()

def f(stdout_lock, next_item, worklist):
    while True:
        with next_item.get_lock():
            if len(worklist) <= next_item.value:
                return
            item = worklist[next_item.value]
            next_item.value += 1
        info('queue item: ', stdout_lock, item)
        time.sleep(0.0001)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    next_item = Value('l')
    worklist = [str(i) for i in range(250000)]
    next_item.value = 0
    stdout_lock = Lock()
    plist = []
    for i in range(3):
        plist.append(Process(target=f, args=(stdout_lock, next_item, worklist)))
        plist[-1].start()
    for i in range(3):
        plist[i].join()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using celery - http://www.celeryproject.org/ - the queue limit would be up to the broker configuration.

Moreover, you would not be limited to workers on the same machine - any computer that could mount the same filesystem could run celery workers to process your tasks. (Although if remote processing then is not an option, using celery workers could still have advantages over raw multiprocessing, as there are niceties such as automatic retry)